# Trouble Migrating database schema to Heroku (Postgres)

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku, database-migration

I have everything set up in my local environment and the code for my website up on the Heroku server, I'm just having serious trouble getting the schema to migrate to the PostgreSQL database on the Heroku server. Whenever I attempt `heroku run python manage.py migrate` I get the following (this would be an initial migration):

```
    Running python manage.py migrate on baseballstatview... up, run.1653      (Free)
    Operations to perform:
    Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions, statview
    Running migrations:
      Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
      Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
      Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
      Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK
      Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
      Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
      Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
      Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
      Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
      Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
      Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
      Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length... OK
      Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK
      Applying statview.0001_initial... OK
```

Which seems fine but then using `heroku pg:info` it tells me I have 0 tables, and even further when I run `heroku run python manage.py showmigrations` this is what I get:

```
    Running python manage.py showmigrations on baseballstatview... up, run.5059 (Free)
    admin
     [ ] 0001_initial
     [ ] 0002_logentry_remove_auto_add
    auth
     [ ] 0001_initial
     [ ] 0002_alter_permission_name_max_length
     [ ] 0003_alter_user_email_max_length
     [ ] 0004_alter_user_username_opts
     [ ] 0005_alter_user_last_login_null
     [ ] 0006_require_contenttypes_0002
     [ ] 0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages
     [ ] 0008_alter_user_username_max_length
    contenttypes
     [ ] 0001_initial
     [ ] 0002_remove_content_type_name
    sessions
     [ ] 0001_initial
    statview
     [ ] 0001_initial
```

So it appears that the migrations are not going through and I'm wondering why that's the case. The database is empty, I've tried resetting it and trying again but nothing seems to work.

EDIT: below is the relevant `settings.py`for dj_database_url:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'mlb_data',
    'USER': 'postgres',
    'PASSWORD': 'pw',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '5432',
 }
}

import dj_database_url

DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config()

SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

DEBUG = False

try:
    from .local_settings import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

Comment: How is your database defined? Are you using [`dj-database-url`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/dj-database-url)?

Comment: @Chris yes I am

Comment: Do you have anything in local_settings? Does it override the database setting?

Comment: @thumbtack_5, and what is your `DATABASE_URL` environment variable on Heroku (make sure to sanitize it to remove the actual host, database name, user, and password)? I realize that's just about everything sanitized, but we need to see it.

Comment: @DanielRoseman @Chris Thanks for both of your input. It does appear that my `local_settings.py` was over-riding `settings.py`

Answer (score 0):

It looks from your code snippet that you are loading your dj_database_url configs BEFORE you attempt to bring in your local settings. This is the problem. What's happening here is that your local settings are overriding the production settings (with Postgres).

What's happening when you run the migration is:

- Heroku is creating a new local SQLite database.
- Doing the migrations.
- Saying it's successful.
- Exiting.

If you move that local settings stuff up above your db_database_url call, things should start magically working for ya!

Comment: Yup you're right. I actually ended up leaving `settings.py` as is and removed the `local_settings.py` from the remote server, which it should never have been on. That way the dev server is still set to `local_settings.py` but the remote is not.

Comment: Perfect! That's awesome =D